# WebBrick server won't start when using MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

I'm new to Rails and when I try creating a new application like this:

```
$ rails new app_one -d mysql
```

It installs and everything works as expected.  But, if I try to run it on a local server with MySQL enabled, it doesn't work.

```
> /Users/matthewpoplin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
```

I'm using Rails version 3.2.13, Ruby version 2.0.0p0, MySQL version 5.6.10, and Homebrew 0.9.4.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure that all the username, password, etc. information for the database is correct in your Rails `database.yml` file?

From looking at this line in your output:

```
 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

it is possible that your password isn't set in the Rails database settings file.  It might be a good idea to double-check your `database.yml` settings file.  *(Or, perhaps, it could be an issue with the database username and password you are wanting to use.)*

And a note for future reference: *it might be good to use a different database user other than "root" in the future, when possible.*